# WebAudio / WaveSurfer : Record AudioContext output?

Tags: webrtc, audio-recording, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I am using multiple [WaveSurfers](http://wavesurfer-js.org) with the region plugin to load samples in a digital instrument. It works great as far as performance goes, but I am trying to give users the ability to record what they play and convert it into a blob or what-have-you. Is there a way to record and save sounds being played in real time within a single AudioContext? So far I have only been able to capture external input from the microphone which is pretty neat.

I was thinking of using WaveSurfer's MediaElement fallback and the captureStream() API, however the MediaElement seems to throw an error unfortunately, reading that it cannot querySelector of undefined.

Here's the code that initializes each WaveSurfer:

```
this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: this.wave_id,
    waveColor: 'black',
    progressColor: 'purple',
    pixelRatio: 1,
    plugins: [
      RegionPlugin.create()
  ]
  });
```

Many thanks!

UPDATE:
I'm only able to record by creating a buffer source, connecting it to the AudioContext destination, and connecting it to a MediaStreamDestination. But I can only do this for each individual WaveSurfer, and when I try to create a buffer for the global AudioContext the WaveSurfers are latching on to, it returns no sound into the stream. Would be grateful for any pointers for recording all global context outputs.

The following records individual WaveSurfer output:

```
//buffer source node passed to media stream from a single wavesurfer instance. instantiated in wavesurfer.jsx component
          this.bufferSource = this.wavesurfer.backend.ac.createBufferSource();
          this.bufferSource.buffer = this.wavesurfer.backend.buffer;
          this.bufferSource.connect(this.wavesurfer.backend.ac.destination);




//method called which records the output and loads a blob into a new 
//wavesurfer (created elsewhere on event emission)

        recordContext(context, source){

        const dest = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);
        source.connect(dest)

        mediaRecorder.start();
        source.start()

         setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        source.stop()
         }, 5000)


        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (evt) => {
         // push each chunk (blobs) in an array
         console.log('you have data')
         this.state.chunks.push(evt.data);
        };

        mediaRecorder.onstop = (evt) => {
         // Make blob and open it.
         let blob = new Blob(this.state.chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
             console.log(blob) 
             let audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        };

     }
```

UPDATE 2:

I've now taken a step in the right direction by merging each buffer into one and passing it into an AudioContext, but the real-time element is missing as this simply concatenates static buffers. Is there a way to capture PCM streaming in real time from each buffer when a user triggers a region of a sample?

Comment: review your api.. find a way to get at the audioBuffer -- exposes  something like byteArray or arrayBuffer...  determine whether bytes in buffer are encoded or raw... if u get that far, then u can copy the buffer and do whatever on the clone... encode it , toBlob it,  append arrays etc.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was wondering which specific property to access and wasn't making sense of MDNs docs. I'll try that and get back to ya.

Comment: I'm back with updates: 

 I'm able to record by creating a buffer source, connecting it to the AudioContext destination, and connecting it to a MediaStreamDestination-- but I can only do this for each individual WaveSurfer. when I try to create a buffer for the global AudioContext the WaveSurfers are latching on to, it returns no sound into the stream. Would be grateful for any pointers for recording all global context outputs.

Comment: reuse of existing context is possible but as the end of this thread shows, and on ios , it can be hairy todo.. https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/324  u may find ez to construct and to use new audioContext rather than reuse existing

Comment: Gotcha. I've now taken a step in the right direction by merging each buffer into one and passing it into an AudioContext, but the real-time element is missing as this simply concatenates static buffers. Is there a way to capture PCM streaming in real time from each buffer when a user triggers a region of a sample?